# Why can't I auto-fit text of a UILabel from code, but I can through the IB?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, autoresize

**Scenario:** I merely want to able to fit a string within a UILabel per target device.  
That is, on one iPad model the string is truncated. On another it isn't.

 I suspect the application is more code-centric vs IB. 
 So I want to be able to work with the UILabel programmatically.

Here's the code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var myLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func addMessageAction(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        let msg = "Mother had a feeling, I might be too appealing. But I can understand."
        myLabel.text = msg
        myLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        myLabel.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true
        myLabel.sizeToFit()

        myLabel.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
        myLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
    }

    @IBAction func exitAction(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        exit(0)
    }
}
```

Here's the screen after I pressed the 'message' button:
[image]

This only appear to work with I set the UILabel properties within IB.

Why doesn't it work via code?

Comment: So you want the text to shrink to fit? Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: I merely want the UILabel to adjust it size to accommodate the entire text.   I see to options: shrink into one line or expand to multiple lines.   I would like to do both; the decide which is appropriate for the task I had to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code and its working perfectly. Is there any Autolayout constraint mismatch ?

You can do one thing to this change the font size to fit the width of the label

```
myLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Debashish gave me the correct answer.
I added his suggestion: `myLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true` and it worked in real time.

Interestingly, I had used the original code snippet in a shared project; and it worked...but not in my small proof-of-concept.

But again, the added myLabel property statement did the trick here.